# Spark SQL combine Array[string] with mark

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have two `Array[string]` columns in MongoDB collection, now I combine it by the Scala `UDF` function as following:

```
def concat_array(arr1: mutable.WrappedArray[String],arr2: 
    mutable.WrappedArray[String]): mutable.WrappedArray[String] =               
    {
        (arr1 ++ arr2)
    }
```

After registed the `UDF` function I use the SparkSQL

```
spark.sql(("select concat_array(arr1,arr2) from table1")
```

to return the associated data, however,  I want to change the result to mark which item in the result come from `arr1` or `arr2`.

Could you please advise any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def concat_array(arr1: mutable.WrappedArray[String],arr2: 
       mutable.WrappedArray[String]): mutable.WrappedArray[(String, Int)] =                
          {
             (arr1.map(_ -> 1) ++ arr2.map(_ -> 2))
          }
```

Output is an array of tuples, element 2 indicates which the source array.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank @Terry